# prove that for every $x\in X$ exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $interior(f(B[x,n]))\not = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be complete metric spaces and let $f\space:\space X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective closed function.
prove that for every $x\in X$ exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $interior(f(B[x,n]))\not = \emptyset$
where $B[x,R]=\{a\in X\space :\space d(x,a)\leq R\}$ and $interior(A)=\bigcup_{S_\alpha\subset A}S$ and each $S$ is open.
note: closed function maps closed set in $X$ to a closed set in $Y$
I assume you have to use Baire category theorem but I cant understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that there exists an $x \in X$ such that for all natural numbers $n$ we have that

$int(f(B[x,n])) = \emptyset$.

Now $B[x,n]$ is a closed set for all $x \in X$ and any natural number $n$.

Since $f$ is a surjective closed map, $Y = f(X) = f( \cup_{n = 1}^\infty B[x,n]) \subseteq \cup_{n = 1}^\infty f(B[x,n])$,

but by our assumption $int(f(B[x,n])) = \emptyset$ for all $n$ so each set $f(B[x,n])$ is nowhere dense and closed.  Hence we have expressed the complete metric space $Y$ as a countable union of nowhere dense closed sets, which contradicts the Baire category theorem.